# Finding two functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions, graphing-functions

I am not sure how to approach this question.  It asks to find $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ such that $h(x)=f(g(x))$, for each function:

a) $$h(x)=\sqrt{x^2 + 6}$$

b)$$h(x)=\frac{1}{x^3}-7x+2$$

If someone could help me, that would be really appreciated.

Comment: For $a$, do you mean $\sqrt{x^2 +6}$ or $\sqrt{x^2} +6$?

Comment: Well there's always the easy way to do it: let $g(x)=x$. :)

Comment: @Bye_World The first one.  Sorry, I didn't know how to use the root tool here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's look at a few different ways to do the first one, then maybe you'll see how to do the second:

1. Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x^2 + 6}$ and $g(x) = x$.  Then $$f(g(x)) = f(x) = \sqrt{(x)^2+6} = h(x)$$
2. That one sorta feels like it's cheating, though, doesn't it?  Let's find a not so trivial way to do it.  How about $f(x) = \sqrt{x+6}$ and $g(x) = x^2$.  Then $$f(g(x)) = f(x^2) = \sqrt{(x^2)+6} = h(x)$$
3. Or how about this one? Let $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ and $g(x)=x^2+6$.  Then $$f(g(x)) = f(x^2+6) = \sqrt{(x^2+6)} = h(x)$$  That one makes both functions really simple -- wouldn't you agree?

As you can see there are multiple ways of doing these types of compositions.  It'd be a good exercise if now you try to find an $f$ and $g$ *different* than any of my examples above.  So give it a try. :)

Comment: so for part b.  I am having some troubles,  I was able to find some for a.  For b it's the division or fraction that throws me off.  Could I use $g(x)=1/x?$ If so, what could I use for f(x)?

Comment: Of course you could.  Your $f$ would have to be some function such that $f(1/x) = \dfrac 1{x^3} -7x+2$.  So now, just replace the $1/x$ with $x$ everywhere in the previous equation and what do you get?

Comment: So would $f(x)=x^3 -7x+2$? My apologies. I am still trying to get comfortable with these kinds of questions.

Comment: No.  If $f(x) = x^3-7x+2$, then $f(g(x)) = \dfrac {1}{x^3} -\dfrac {7}{x}+2$ -- which is not what $h(x)$ is in your question.  So then how do we do it?  First let's rewrite the RHS of the equation in my previous comment to make it more explicitly a function of $1/x$.  Then we get $f(1/x) = (1/x)^3 -7(1/x)^{-1} +2$.  Thus $f(x) = x^3-7x^{-1} +2 = x^3-\dfrac {7}{x}+2$.  Then you can verify that $f(g(x)) = \dfrac {1}{x^3}-7x+2 = h(x)$ as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always take $g(x)=x$, and $f(x) = h(x)$. Then, you have $f(g(x)) = h(g(x)) = x$ and you are done.